# restart looping - turn-on & turn-off every seconds

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

For 4 days my computer worked fine. Yesterday morning I've launched my pc.

Everything was fine for one hour, I even didn't touch the computer, I was near by, looking video on my laptop PC.

Then everything shut down. The lights of the motherboard started flashing. I've stopped it and started to figure why the computer can't start again...

I can see that the mother board is loop restarting, every seconds.

I've removed the graphic card, changed the DRAM disposition, unplug everything thats is not required. Nothing changes.

Couple of hours later, the computer started again, **but after 5 minutes** it shutted down and go back to the restarting loop...

This morning ? AGAIN. The computer starts normaly, so I decided to launch a memory test. But again, after a couple of minutes it shutted down, and go back to the restarting loop...

**Important :**  **Every couple of hours, the computer will boot normaly, and I can use the computer for everything for 5 to 10 minutes, after that it's the loop again**

And yes, it's not the heat, my CPU is cold.

I have no idea what I've could done wrong :'(

I hope this is just the PSU...

any ideas ?

---

MSI MotherBoard Gaming m3

I7 6700K

Advance Premium Power 650w

Comment: Try starting in safe mode and see if it stays on longer.

Comment: Sounds like a heating issue. Make sure all your fans are not clogged and rotating. You already mention you checked t he CPU one, but the system has more, for example the one for the PSU, video card, etc.

Comment: How to use safe mode ?

I don't this this is a heat problem, the video card is removed, le cpu fan run correctly and the cpu stays at a good 25-30 degrees C, and the PSU is literally cold when I touch it ...

Answer (score 0):

i think maybe your power have a problem but in past my pc like your pc in every 1 hours or 2 hours it restart and i buy Silicone pastes and use that on my cpu and then problem of it solved maybe for you like my problem. try it

Comment: actually it's not restarting every 1 or 2 hours. If I let all power off for 2 hours, the PC will start, and go well for 5 minutes, after that it will turn off and turn on ever seconds
So maybe I thinks it's the PSU